# Find out image tiles falling under bounding box efficiently

Tags: java, performance, spatial

I am working in Java. I have a large image made up of randomly sized rectangular tiles. I want to store the information about these tiles such a way in my program that, given a rectangle bounding box, I can quickly find out which tiles will fall inside this rectangle. At present I am doing this by iterating over each tile bounding box to check  this. But I am looking for a quick way to find this as the number of tiles is very high.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you thought of creating a dictionary which his key is the bounding box. upon given bounding box you get the relevant tiles. you can then think of creating a override add\get function for it which do the check if the tiles fall inside the rectangle. (really depends on you)

Comment: sorry, didn't understand your suggestion. If I got it correctly, it will still be O(N) solution?

Comment: You can narrow your array by splitting it up according to their widths, like 0-10, 10-20, 20-30, 30- 40, 40-50 pixels which will return an array just containing the width of the box. Then you can iterate over each element? Hashmaps are also very usefull to index elements. which is much more faster then iterating over arrays...

Comment: regarding the complexity, it is really depends on the framework you are using. as advised by @sgpalit you can use hashset which the framework does the performance considerations for you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quad trees were made for this kind of thing if I understand your question correctly. They're a 4-ary spatial partitioning tree.

A basic implementation is like this:

1. Start with one big root node encompassing the whole image with a
   bounding rectangle that encompasses it. It's currently a leaf (has no
   children).
2. Now start inserting elements (your rectangles) to it.
3. When inserting to a node, if it's a leaf, insert the element if it doesn't have too many elements yet (ex: less than 4). If it has too
   many elements, split that leaf into 4 quadrants, turning it into a
   branch, and transfer the elements to the appropriate quadrants. If it's a branch, insert the element to the appropriate child quadrant(s).
4. Repeat until you've inserted everything, forming a search hierarchy in the process.

Now when you want to find out what elements (rectangles) are inside a search rectangle, start at the root of this structure and work your way down recursively into the quadrants that intersect this rectangle until you reach leaf nodes, at which point you can just check the elements inside those leaf nodes.

Another way that's a bit simpler and can work better for very dynamic data (ex: if your rectangles are moving around each frame) is a fixed-size NxN grid. Simply insert your elements (rectangles) into the cells they intersect. When searching, simply search the elements inside the grid cells that your search rectangle intersects.

The quad tree is simply an 'adaptive grid' extension of this basic idea.

Comment: Thank you! :) I was looking for a solution you have described!